# Accessing a superclass's superclass variable/method

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java, I have a class A which has a function say 'funA'. I have a subclass B which has again a function 'funA' which overrides it. And a class C which is a sublcass of B and has a function 'funA' which also overrides it. How can I access the function 'funA' from class C?

```
class A {   

 public void funA() {
    System.out.println("a in A...........");
 }
}
class B extends A {

 public void funA() {
     System.out.println("a in B...............");
 }

}

class C extends B { 
  //How to access 'funA' of A from here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the class `B` overrides it. It would be possible only if the method in `B` had different signature than the method in `A` or if `C` extended directly class `A`.

This is very well described in Oracle's [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This is not a good way to use inheritance. If B is not appropriate for C, don't extends it. For more detail about inheritance, please refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Hope this help.